# Is there such thing as an OS "internal firewall"

Tags: firewalls, operating-systems

I was wondering if there is such thing as an OS "internal firewall". If it exists, it must be under a different name.

I am looking for a way to control which applications can talk to which other applications inside of a single computer.

I am not only asking about TCP/IP sockets, but also UNIX-domain sockets, pipes, and all other IPC mechanisms...

I have found this
http://www.tresys.com/innovation/papers/Securing-IPC-in-SELinux.pdf
But it is only about making channels unidirectional. It suggests that security for bidirectional channels has already been solved, but I cannot find more information.

Note that covert channels are another issue and not the subject of this question.

Comment: Perhaps the term "sandbox"?

Comment: Sandbox is the generic term; different operating systems have more specific terms. There's OS-level virtualization solutions (e.g. OpenVZ), and that uses Linux Containers. Then there are FreeBSD jails. And there's Selinux if you don't necessarily want to go as far as containers, but you want to enforce some very strict / specific constraints on applications.

Answer (score 1):

> But it is only about making channels unidirectional. It suggests that security for bidirectional channels has already been solved, but I cannot find more information.

It suggests that a bi-directional channel is simply a pair of uni-directional channels.

By the way, they hardly "solve" the problem of uni-directional channels, due to the "back channels" described. Sure, the bandwidth of a back channel is low. But how much bandwidth do you need to steal critical data like an encryption key, passphrase or a private key? Answer: 128 bits for either of the first two, 2888 bits for an SSH-format ECDSA private key. Even if you can only transfer one bit per second (a very pessimal estimate), 2888 bits is less than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

The [process firewalls](http://siis.cse.psu.edu/pfwall/)  - a resource access protection mechanism that  inspects both the program and the system, might come handy for you. It works similar to network firewalls – an OS authorization system allows resource access based on the firewall rules.